# Sigma.js: How to create fullscreen & zoom control buttons in a Sigma.js webapp using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sigma.js

I am working on a Sigma.js webapp and need to implement primarily a full screen (and zoom-in and out buttons as well).
While it is very easy to implement with [React-Sigma controls](https://sim51.github.io/react-sigma/docs/example/controls/), I cannot use the library for some reasons and need to use vanilla JS with just Sigma.js

How can I add these buttons?